The auto complete in my VS code running a vite project doesn't show the suggestions for .module.css files
When I'm importing css module files or any .css files in my components:
import classes from './'
In CRA projects, after I type that ./ it shows suggestions of files in the folder like this:

But in vite projects, only the folders and .jsx files are shown by vs code:

Well, I know that vite only allows files to be .jsx and not .js, so I am guessing this problem may be somewhat related to that but I may be wrong about that.
I briefly checked the docs but could not find anything, I thought like adding something to vite.config.js file or something....
The vite config file is the default one made when the project was initiated by npm:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()]
})

The import works fine but not getting the auto completion and to type the whole thing is a little hassle and sometimes there may be typos. If anyone knows something please help.
